# Pie chart rotation using d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Im new to d3.js im able to create donut chart and im able to rotate chart but i dont want labels on chart to rotate. Can anyone help how to proceed. how shall i make sure that labels on chart should not rotate

```
    var dataset = [
        {
            count: 10
        },
        {
            count: 20
        },
        {
            label: 'Cantaloupe',
            count: 30
        }
    ];

    var width = 360;
    var height = 360;
    var radius = 100;

    var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .range(["red", "blue", "green"]);
    var svg = d3.select('body')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', width)
        .attr('height', height)
        .append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (width / 2) +
            ',' + (height / 2) + ')');

    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius(radius - 60)
        .outerRadius(radius);

    var pie = d3.layout.pie()
        .value(function (d) {
            return d.count;
        });

    var arcs = svg.selectAll('.arc')
        .data(pie(dataset))
        .enter()
        .append('g')
        .attr("class", "arc");
    arcs.append("path")
        .attr("d", arc)
        .attr("fill", function (d) {
            return color(d.data.count);
        })
        .on("click", function (d) {
            var curAngle = 180;
            svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ") rotate(" + curAngle + ")");

        });
    arcs.append("text")
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
            return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
        }).attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("font-size", "1.5em")
        .text(function (d) {
            return d.data.count
        });
```

Comment: you still want them to turn with the donut chart but the actual text not to rotate right ? By the way create a JSFiddle so we can test some stuff out